# Как сделать radiobutton отмеченной сразу

Tags: запрос, form, get

Есть форма на сайте с двумя radio с одинаковыми именами и значениями 1 и 2 соответственно. Сайт не мой, код поэтому править не могу. Хочу сделать ссылку на страницу с этой формой, чтобы при переходе по ней один из radio был отмечен.

Можно ли сделать так?

Comment: Как то непонятно? вы хотите перейти на чужой сайт и иметь свои значения по умолчанию?

Comment: грубо говоря, да. Т.е. в ссылке передать команду браузеру, чтобы он отметил радиобатон

Comment: Это почти нереально. Попробуйте яваскриптом обратиться к форме в дочернем окне. Но скорее всего, некоторые браузеры такое поведение заблочат из-за несовпадающих доменов.

Comment: Можно же get-ом передавать заполнение полей..
http://domain.org?name5=4
объект <input name=name5> будет иметь значение 4 при переходе. С радиобатоном чет не получается такое..

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type = "radio" checked = "checked" />
```

Comment: извиняюсь, но как это встроить в ссылку?
Мне нужно что-то вроде:
http://domain.org?<необходимый мне текст>

Comment: Мне нужно что-то вроде:// Если бы все было так просто, фишинг бы процветал буйным цветом. К счастью, кросс-доменные изменения возможны только после очень долгого согласования хэдеров. Так что проще договориться с владельцем сайта о введении АПИ